# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, opencv

Hola tengo un problema me da error que no es callable  y no se que pasa no configo descubrir como pasar la funcion con sus variables. Alguien me puede clarificar que es lo que esta esperando fl_time.

```
from moviepy.editor import CompositeVideoClip, VideoFileClip, TextClip, concatenate_videoclips,vfx
import time
import math

clip2 = VideoFileClip("F:/ave-maria-mosca.mp4")

tiem=0.0
tiempo_ralentizado=4   #4 segundos
lugar_ralentizado=5   #En el segundo 5
Framerate=50
arco_ralen=tiempo_ralentizado*Framerate


def tiempo(tiem,tiempo_ralentizado,lugar_ralentizado,Framerate,arco_ralen):
    gek=tiem
    punto_entrada=lugar_ralentizado -( tiempo_ralentizado /2 )
    calcular=abs(math.sin(gek/4)*2)
    return gek+1- calcular

clip2 = clip2.fl_time( tiempo(tiem,tiempo_ralentizado,lugar_ralentizado,Framerate,arco_ralen) ).set_duration(40)
```

El error que aparece es este

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\post-produccion.py", line 36, in <module>
    clip2 = clip2.fl_time( tiempo(tiem,tiempo_ralentizado,lugar_ralentizado,Framerate,arco_ralen) ).set_duration(40)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 190, in fl_time
    return self.fl(lambda gf, t: gf(t_func(t)), apply_to,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 138, in fl
    newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-57>", line 2, in set_make_frame
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 14, in outplace
    f(newclip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 666, in set_make_frame
    self.size = self.get_frame(0).shape[:2][::-1]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-10>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 138, in <lambda>
    newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 190, in <lambda>
    return self.fl(lambda gf, t: gf(t_func(t)), apply_to,
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'float' object is not callabl
```

Alguien me puede ayudar y decirme que pasa en el codigo.Stackoverflow me obliga aescribir mas palabras y no se que contaros.

Saludos

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el error que te aparece tal cual para que podamos ver en que línea falla y la descripción completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con la documentación:

**fl_time(self, t_func, apply_to=None, keep_duration=False)**

> Returns a Clip instance playing the content of the current clip but
> with a modified timeline, time t being replaced by another time
> t_func(t).
> Parameters
>
> ```
> t_func:    A function t-> new_t
> ```

Tienes que llamar a `fl_time()` pasando una función como primer argumento. Más aún, esta función tiene un único parámetro `t` (el tiempo original).

Ejemplo:

```
>>> # plays the clip (and its mask and sound) twice faster
>>> newclip = clip.fl_time(lambda: 2*t, apply_to=['mask', 'audio'])
>>>
>>> # plays the clip starting at t=3, and backwards:
>>> newclip = clip.fl_time(lambda: 3-t)
```

Pero la función `tiempo` que defines 1) requiere múltiples parámetros, 2) no estás pasando **la función**; pasas **el valor** de la función con ciertos parámetros.

La llamada correcta tendría que ser

```
clip2 = clip2.fl_time(tiempo).set_duration(40)
```

pero tendrías que redefinir la función `tiempo` para que acepte un sólo parámetro.

Comment: Buenos días, si el ejemplo de lambda lo había visto pero como le quiero meter parametros dentro..... Entonces que hago los paso como variables globales, o hay otra manera. Saludos

Comment: @virtualsets. Variables globales es la solución más rápida, aunque no se si sea la función está bien planteada.

Comment: jajaja eso seguro. Yo no soy programador a tiempo completo, solo de vez en cuando me pongo para solucionarme algún tema de psot producción, gráficos....y siempre mis scripts solo valen para mi por que si lo ve un programador se tira de los pelos